# using interop .word with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, interop

I used interop to write a word document with a template (.dot) file.

It's working with Visual Studio even on server, but it's not working via ISS on server.

I dont understand what the problem is. It shows error: a word error ? form this line:

`line 326: oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);`

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use interop in server applications, because "Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."
Try to use OpenXML to generate your document correctly.